# MongoDB - update sub document using $set

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have this document:

```
{ "data" : "AP1IUY9Bfp", "me" : { "something" : "somevalue" } }
```

I have this object:

```
webpage: 'stackoverflow'
```

How can I $push/$set this field into document.me, so the final result will equal:

```
{ "data" : "AP1IUY9Bfp", "me" : { "something" : "somevalue", "webpage": "stackoverflow" } }
```

If I try this using `$set`, like this:

```
db.collection('doc').update({id: 'AP1IUY9Bfp'}, {'$set': {'me': webpage: 'stackoverflow'}}
```

The result equals:

```
{ "data" : "AP1IUY9Bfp", "me" : { "webpage" : "stackoverflow" } }
```

(it overwrites the field)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you'll want to do is something like this:

```
{'$set': {'me.webpage': 'stackoverflow'} }
```

Note the only difference is that I'm using dot notation to point to a sub-document.

Think about it as you would a normal JSON object outside of Mongo. You use dot notation to access properties of objects - mongo works the same way.

Here is a link to the relevant documentation regarding subdocuments and the dot notation in mongo - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation

> ### Dot Notation
>
> MongoDB uses the dot notation to access the elements of an array and to access the fields of a subdocument.
>
> ...
>
> To access a field of a subdocument with dot-notation, concatenate the
>   subdocument name with the dot (.) and the field name, and enclose in
>   quotes:
>
> `'<subdocument>.<field>'`

Comment: Thanks Lix! What would you do if you have an object containing multiple entries that you want to set?

Comment: @subZero - I would do the same as a regular update but specify more items in the `$set` document. Take a look at [this section](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#add-new-fields) of the update documentation. You'll see that `mbranch` and `"name.aka"` are being updated together in one query.

Comment: You are most welcome @subZero! Big fan of your work in the Mortal Combat series BTW :P Happy coding!

Answer (score -3):

mustn´t it be

```
 db.collection('doc').update({id: 'AP1IUY9Bfp'}, {'me': $set: { webpage: 'stackoverflow'}}
```

Comment: `{'me': $set: { webpage: 'stackoverflow'}}` is simply not a valid object.